# Sorting an array from lowest to greatest

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

So i'm in my first programming class and am having some trouble with an assignment. The assignment was to make a code that asks the user for six integers and six letters and to store them in arrays. Then print a bar graph with the data sorted from lowest to highest. That is the part i am having trouble with. I named it the Arrange function, and to me everything looks right. I was just hoping someone could tell me where i went wrong in swapping the lowest integer. Any other comments on the code would be much appreciated! Thanks   (I also cant use sort functions from a library, or pointers)

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Arrange(int num[],int order[],char let[],char letOrder[],int cap);
void Swap(int order[],char let[],int a,int b);
void BuildGraph(int number[],char letter[],int max);
int getMax(int number[]);
```

int main(){

```
int Number[6];
char Letter[6];
int Order[6];
char LetterOrder[6];
int max;

cout<<"Please Enter 6 Integers: ";         //gets 6 integers
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    cout<<"Ineteger # "<<i+1<<" = ";
    cin>>Number[i];
    cout<<endl;
}
cout<<"Please Enter 6 Characters: ";       //gets 6 characters
for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
    cout<<"Enter a character here: ";
    cin>>Letter[i];
    cout<<endl;
}

max= getMax(Number);

BuildGraph(Number,Letter,max);

Arrange(Number,Order,Letter,LetterOrder,max);

BuildGraph(Order,LetterOrder,max);



return 0;
```

}

```
int getMax(int number[]){
    int max=number[0];                         
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++){
        if(max<number[i]) max=number[i];
    }
    return max;
}


void Arrange(int num[],int order[],char let[],char letOrder[],int cap){
    int i,n;
    order=num;
    letOrder=let;
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
        for(n=0;n<6;n++){
            if(order[i]>order[n]){
                Swap(order,letOrder,i,n);
            }
        }
    }
    cout<<order[4];
}

void Swap(int order[],char let[],int a,int b){
    int temp1=order[b];
    order[b]=order[a];
    order[a]=temp1;
    int temp2=let[b];
    let[b]=let[a];
    let [a]=temp2;
}

void BuildGraph(int number[],char letter[],int max){
    cout<<"Bar Chart"<<endl;
for(int row=max;row>=1;row--){             
    for(int col=0;col<6;col++){
        if(row<=number[col]) cout<<letter[col]<<" ";
        else cout<<"  ";
    }
    cout<<endl;
}
}
```

Comment: Wait, you can't use pointers, but you're using arrays as function argument types? They're basically the same thing in C++.

Comment: Yeah i think we are learning pointers next, but my Professor doesn't allow us to hand in hw with things we havent gone over in class.

Answer (score 0):

It would probably be easier to visualize and implement if you have separate functions for arrange and swap.

```
void arrangeNum(int num[])
void arrangeChar(char char[])
void swapInt(int x, int y)
void swapChar(char x, char y)
```

Then the arrange functions will just be bubble sorts.  But you also lose scope when calling swap so they don't actually do anything.  It would be easier to just swap them within the Arrange functions.